# How to call a node function from client-side javascript? (HTML)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, ajax

I have a node app called `index.js` that runs express. A while ago I decided to merge a website template and my node app together and everything works fine up to here. I am able to load other paths into the node app (`index.js`) by using the below code.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.use('/assets', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/assets')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/')));
```

Now, I am able to serve different html pages using express, which means my app is able to access the `assets` folder and the content inside the folder.

Now, the assets folder contains other folders called js, css and... The HTML template is loading all it's javascript codes from the `js` folder in `assets`. Note the javascript codes are not written in the HTML file. Here's an example of how a script is triggered in my HTML code:

```
<script src="../../assets/js/test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            test.theFunction();
        });
    </script>
```

And here's the javascript code in the following directory:

```
// assets/js/test.js
test = {
  theFunction: function() {
    res.send("finally...");
    console.log("sup?");
  }
}
```

I am trying to call the following function inside `index.js` from `test.js`:

```
// /index.js
app.get("/hey", function(req, res) {
  res.send("wassaaa!!");
});
```

So far, I've tried the following code, but it doesn't call the function:

```
  $.get('/hey').success(function(response) {
    $scope.final = response;
    console.log(response);
  });
```

I've also tried `module.exports` in `index.js`, but when I require it in `test.js` I get an error saying that I can't require stuff on the client side.

I've also looked at some examples regarding require.js, but the examples mostly explain how to load require.js in the HTML file rather than directly in a js file.

To sum it up, here's what I want to happen: HTML file triggers the functions in `test.js`, then `test.js` gets some data from `index.js` and passes it to the HTML file again... I am trying to avoid writing the javascript codes in the HTML file.

I'm also open to suggestions if anyone knows how to achieve what I am trying to do in an easier way. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You should write the function in `test.js` and import it into `index.js`. For example, a function `getResponse()` that returns "wassaaa!!" in test.js, and in index.js use `res.send(test.getResponse())`

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more? I'm not sure what you mean by importing the function in test.js into index.js? I did mention that module.exports and require don't work as I get an error when loading it in the browser (client-side). Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Assuming you transpile ES6, you can use `export default { something }` and in index.js you can use `import { something } from 'test.js'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the URL to achieve that. Here is an example to your dev environment, supposing your app is listening on port 8800:

```
$.get('http://localhost:8800/hey').success(function(response) {
  $scope.final = response;
  console.log(response);
});
```